# SerializationException: error parsing file

Tags: json

So I'm trying to splice code together (not exactly a programming genius) to spruce up my version of the open-source game Destination Sol. Upon loading a new game, I receive the fatal error:

SerializationException: Error parsing file: res/configs/planets.json (file is essentially putting allies and enemies on planets and setting them up)

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: res/configs/planets.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
    at org.destinationsol.game.planet.PlanetConfigs.<init>(PlanetConfigs.java:48)
    at org.destinationsol.game.planet.PlanetManager.<init>(PlanetManager.java:53)
    at org.destinationsol.game.SolGame.<init>(SolGame.java:121)
    at org.destinationsol.SolApplication.startNewGame(SolApplication.java:171)
    at org.destinationsol.menu.LoadingScreen.updateCustom(LoadingScreen.java:46)
    at org.destinationsol.ui.SolInputManager.update(SolInputManager.java:220)
    at org.destinationsol.SolApplication.update(SolApplication.java:132)
    at org.destinationsol.SolApplication.safeUpdate(SolApplication.java:111)
    at org.destinationsol.SolApplication.render(SolApplication.java:91)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing JSON on line 206 near:
blaster|waveGun:0.1 a1|a2:.5 s1|s2:.5",
          density: 0.1,
      },
    ],
    groundEnemies: [
      {
        hull: techieSmall,
        items: "fixedPlasmaGun fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster:.5 a2:.5 s3|s4",
        money: 120,
        density: 0.25,
      }
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:548)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:55)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
    ... 11 more
```

I was hoping someone who understands .json files better than me could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Also, here's the entire planets.json for reference:

```
{
  rocky: {
    easyOnly: true,
    minGrav: 0.4,
    maxGrav: 0.6,
    groundTexs: "grounds/rocky",
    decoTexs: "deco/rocky",
    cloudTexs: "skies/cloud",
    rowCount: 4,
    smoothLandscape: true,
    sky: {
      dawnColor: "hsb 0 50 100",
      dayColor: "hsb 216 40 100",
    },
    deco: {
      grass: {
        density: 0.3,
        szMin: 0.1,
        szMax: 0.2,
        orig: "0 0.5",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
      tree: {
        density: 0.4,
        szMin: 0.7,
        szMax: 0.8,
        orig: "0 0.5",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
    },

    highOrbitEnemies: [
      {
        hull: pirateOrbiter,
        items: "plasmaGun|blaster s1:.24",
        money: 40,
        density: 0.03,
      }
    ],
    lowOrbitEnemies: [
      {
        hull: pirateOrbiter,
        items: "bombGun s1:.24",
        money: 50,
        density: 0.1,
      },
    ],
    groundEnemies: [
      {
        hull: piratePlanetTurret,
        items: "plasmaGun|blaster s1:.36",
        money: 110,
        density: 0.45,
      },
      {
        hull: pirateSmall,
        items: "blaster|gun s1|s2:.5",
        money: 60,
        density: 0.15,
      },
    ],
    station: {
      hull: drome,
      items: "gun|shotGun s2 rep:1:4",
    },

    trading: {
      items: "rep plasmaClip shotGun shellClip mineClip bombGun bombClip missileClip s2 unShieldCharge",
      ships: "pirateSmall pirateOrbiter pirateMedium",
      mercenaries: [
        {
          hull: pirateSmall,
          items: "blaster|gun s1 rep:1:3",
          money: 100,
        },
      ],
    },
  },



  desert: {
    minGrav: 0.6,
    maxGrav: 0.8,
    groundTexs: "grounds/desert",
    decoTexs: "deco/desert",
    cloudTexs: "skies/cloud",
    rowCount: 3,
    smoothLandscape: true,
    sky: {
      dawnColor: "hsb 130 50 100",
      dayColor: "hsb 200 40 100",
    },
    deco: {
      tree: {
        density: 0.25,
        szMin: 0.5,
        szMax: 0.7,
        orig: "0 0.5",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
      remnant: {
        density: 0.05,
        szMin: 1,
        szMax: 1.1,
        orig: "0 0.3",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
      cactus: {
        density: 0.5,
        szMin: 0.2,
        szMax: 0.4,
        orig: "0 0.5",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
    },

    highOrbitEnemies: [
      {
        hull: desertOrbiter,
        items: "fixedGun a1:.25",
        money: 150,
        density: 0.03,
      }
    ],
    lowOrbitEnemies: [
      {
        hull: desertOrbiter,
        items: "fixedBombGun a1:.25",
        money: 100,
        density: 0.1,
      },
    ],
    groundEnemies: [
      {
        hull: desertPlanetTurret,
        items: "gun a1|a2:.5",
        money: 80,
        density: 0.45,
      },
      {
        hull: desertSmall,
        items: "fixedGun fixedGun:.3 a2:.75",
        money: 80,
        density: 0.15,
      },
    ],
    station: {
      hull: drome,
      items: "shotGun s3 a3 rep:1:4",
    },

    trading: {
      items: "rep teleportCharge fixedGun bulletClip railClip cannon slugClip bombClip a3",
      ships: "desertOrbiter desertSmall desertMedium",
      mercenaries: [
        {
          hull: desertOrbiter,
          items: "fixedBombGun a1:.25 rep:1:3",
          money: 150,
        },
      ],
    },
  },



  frozen: {
    hardOnly: true,
    minGrav: 0.8,
    maxGrav: 1.2,
    rowCount: 4,
    smoothLandscape: true,
    groundTexs: "grounds/frozen",
    decoTexs: "deco/frozen",
    cloudTexs: "skies/cloud",
    sky: {
      dawnColor: "hsb 50 50 100",
      dayColor: "hsb 125 40 100",
    },
    deco: {
      tree: {
        density: 0.4,
        szMin: 0.7,
        szMax: 0.8,
        orig: "0 0.5",
        allowFlip: true,
      },
    },

    highOrbitEnemies: [
      {
        hull: techieOrbiter,
        items: "fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster|fixedEmGun:.5 a2:.75 s4",
        money: 140,
        density: 0.06,
      }
    highOrbitAllies: [
      {
          hull: imperialBig,
          items: "fixedGun fixedShotGun a2|a3|a4 s2|s3|s4”,
          density: 0.01,
       },
      {
          hull: imperialSmall,
          items: "blaster|waveGun:0.1 a1|a2:.5 s1|s2:.5", (<== The line that is causing an error)
          density: 0.1,
      },
    ],
    groundEnemies: [
      {
        hull: techieSmall,
        items: "fixedPlasmaGun fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster:.5 a2:.5 s3|s4",
        money: 120,
        density: 0.25,
      },
      {
        hull: techiePlanetTurret,
        items: "waveGun emGun:.6 a3 s4",
        money: 180,
        density: 0.45,
      },
    ],
   groundAllies: [
      {
        hull: imperialSmall,
        items: “shotGun a1:.5 s1:.5",
        density: 0.5,
      },
       {
        hull: imperialMedium,
        items: "fixedGun a2|a4:.5 s2|s3:.75",
        density: 0.15,
      },
    ]
  station: {
      hull: drome,
      items: "gun|shotGun|waveGun| a4 s4 rep:1:30”,
    },

    trading: {
      items: "rep ",
      ships: "imperialSmall imperialMedium imperialBig techieSmall techieOrbiter",
      mercenaries: [
        {
          hull: imperialSmall,
          items: "blaster|gun|waveGun a1:0.5 s1 rep:1:8",
          money: 75,
        },
        {
         hull: imperialMedium,
         items: "fixedGun|fixedShotGun|fixedPlasmaGun a1|a2 s1|s2 rep:1:12",
         money: 150
        },
        {
         hull: imperialBig,
         items: "fixedGun|fixedShotGun|fixedPlasmaGun fixedGun|fixedShotGun|fixedPlasmaGun:0.5 a2|a3|a4 s2|s3|s4 rep:1:48”,
         money: 300,
        },
        {
         hull: techieOrbiter,
         items: "fixedGun|fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster fixedGun|fixedPlasmaGun|fixedBlaster|fixedEmGun:.5 a2|a3|a4 s2|s3|s4 rep:1:48”,
         money: 300,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```